# How to find my lost partition through Ubuntu installation process?

Tags: system-installation, partition-table

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 but when I choose "other options" and try to format some partitions, my previously `sdb5` partition with 250GB space is lost and I can not find it and there is no option to get it back(at least I cant see).

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you made a backup as advertise by the installer ? Do you know the old fs partition table and what is the new partition table

Comment: No, I only knew the name of partition and it's volume. I preferred to put a Windows CD and use it's partition options to find and delete my hidden partition on Linux.

Comment: "_find and delete_"...? If you've deleted it, it's no longer there. Since that's probably not what you mean, please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Your best bet is probably https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: That the first time I heard about windows being "better" at formatting